# Spotify Webplayback SDK is not defined in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, spotify

So I have a relatively fresh reactjs project setup where my parent component is trying to initialize the spotify webplayback SDK. The only problem im facing here is that everytieme I try to initialize the SDK with the Spotify class it complains that Spotify is undefined.

Now the way the docs on https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/reference/#initializing-the-sdk described it was that I needed to immediately define window.onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady after I call their SDK, so this is what my return html looks like:

```
return (
        <div>
            REEEEEE
            <script src='https://sdk.scdn.co/spotify-player.js' onLoad={handleScriptLoad()}></script>
            <script>
                window.onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady = () = {">"} {
                    handleInit()
                };
            </script>
        </div>
    );
```

This seems to work fine and even manages to call the specified handleInit method, but the moment I try to add the Spotify reference it complains. All examples I find online seem to just call it without any reference from what I see. Any idea how this is meant to work in ReactJS?

Working function:

```
function handleInit() 
    {
        console.log('awwwww man');
      
    }
```

Non working function:

```
function handleInit() 
    {
        console.log('awwwww man');
        const token = props.token;
        const player = new Spotify.Player({
                name: 'Web Playback SDK Quick Start Player',
                getOAuthToken: cb => { cb(token); },
                volume: 0.5
        });

        player.connect();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to add the following line to `index.html` instead of a component.

```
<script src="https://sdk.scdn.co/spotify-player.js"></script>
```

Now, in your React app you can write a hook that tells if it is ready, and consume the hook and the SDK wherever you need in your code:

```
const useIsSpotifyReady = ()=>{
 const [isReady, setIsReady = useState(false)

 useEffect()=>{
  window.onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady = () => {
    setReady(true)
  };
 }
 
 return isReady
}
```

Another alternative is to use a [react-spotify-web-playback-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-spotify-web-playback-sdk) which they already provide a solution for it:

```
mport { WebPlaybackSDK } from "react-spotify-web-playback-sdk";

const AUTH_TOKEN = "your token here!";

const MySpotifyPlayer: React.VFC = () => {
  const getOAuthToken = useCallback(callback => callback(AUTH_TOKEN), []);

  return (
    <WebPlaybackSDK
      deviceName="My awesome Spotify app"
      getOAuthToken={getOAuthToken}
      volume={0.5}>
      {/* `TogglePlay` and `SongTitle` will be defined later. */}
      <TogglePlay />
      <SongTitle />
    </WebPlaybackSDK>
  );
};
```

Comment: Ey that did the trick, just forgot I had an index.html for a second

Comment: Happy to hear it helped. Have a nice day!